# When using Text Input When Keyboard is not on screen the background image is fine but when keyboard is on screen image bottom comes above the keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I Got this problem When using Text Input When Keyboard is not on screen the background image is fine but when keyboard is on screen image bottom comes above the keyboard .. the code for login page and image is given below I tried using the Keyboard avoid view and safeareaview but nothing seems to work out

[image: Without using Keyboard]

[image: When Using Keyboard]

**LoginScreen.js**

```
  import React from "react";
  import  {SafeAreaView,TextInput,Image,View,Text,StatusBar,StyleSheet,KeyboardAvoidingView,TouchableOpacity, TouchableOpacityComponent} from "react-native";
  import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component{

state={
    name:"",
    error:""
}

onPressIcons=()=>{
    this.props.navigation.navigate("About")
}

onPressNextPage=()=>{
    if(this.state.name===""){
        this.setState({error:"Enter A User Name"})
    }
    else{
        this.props.navigation.navigate("Navigate",{name:this.state.name})
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="transparent"/>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.form} >

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.icon} onPress={this.onPressIcons}>
                    <Icon name="ios-contact" size={45} color="#108786"/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <Image source={require("../assets/logo.png")} style={styles.image}/>

                <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.error}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.username}>Username</Text>

                <TextInput style={styles.input} 
                    placeholder="UserName" 
                    onChangeText={name =>{this.setState({name})}}
                    value={this.state.name}/>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>


        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
    }
   }
 const styles=StyleSheet.create({
container:{
    flex:0,
    backgroundColor:"#108786",
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center"
},
form:{
    alignContent:"center",
    alignSelf:"center",
    alignItems:"center",
    elevation:24,
    height:"100%",
    width:"100%",
    backgroundColor:"#FFF",
    borderRadius:45,
    borderTopStartRadius:0,
    borderTopEndRadius:0,
    borderBottomStartRadius:0,
    borderBottomEndRadius:600
   },
   icon:{
        marginTop:90,
        marginLeft:300
   },
   image:{
       height:150,
       width:200,
       alignSelf:"center"
   },
   error:{
        marginTop:7,
        alignSelf:"center",
        color:"red",
        fontSize:15
   },
   username:{
        color:"#108786",
        fontSize:27,
        fontWeight:"bold",
        alignSelf:"center",
        justifyContent:"center",
        marginRight:280,
        marginTop:10
    },
    input:{
        marginTop:15,
        marginRight:100,
        height:50,
        width:380,
        marginLeft:100,
        borderWidth:StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderColor:"#018786",
        borderRadius:10,
        fontWeight:"600",
        paddingHorizontal:16,
        alignSelf:"center",
        borderBottomRightRadius:30,
        borderTopRightRadius:30
    }
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping the KeyboardAvoidingNew component all over the loginScreen. You can make use of just a View component. That should work well

Comment: Thank You It Worked Well ... And I Have Possibly Found Another Solution. By Assigning the width and height of the device ( Using Dimensions ) to the keyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: Nice, glad I could help